# WTForms: Optional validator skipping even though data exists

Tags: python, wtforms

Here's the distilled code:

```py
from wtforms import (
    Form,
    StringField,
    validators,
)


class UserForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[
        validators.Optional(),
        validators.Email(),
    ])


form = UserForm(data={'email': ''})
form.validate()
print(form.errors)  # No errors as expected

form = UserForm(data={'email': 'lem'})
form.validate()
print(form.errors)  # This should have an error

form = UserForm(data={'email': 'lem@email.com'})
form.validate()
print(form.errors)  # No errors as expected
```

Output:

```
{}
{}
{}
```

It looks like having Optional skips succeeding validations whether there is data in the field or not. I suspect it may have something to do with passing a dict through data. I'm not sure.

Removing `validators.Optional` gives me what I expect:

```
{'email': ['Invalid email address.']}
{'email': ['Invalid email address.']}
{}
```

This being an email field with Email validator isn't relevant. The same issue exists even when I have `validators.Length(min=5)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact that you are using the `data` argument rather than `formdata` to initialise your form. According to the documentation `formdata` is used to pass data coming from the enduser following a post request whereas `data` and `obj` are used to provide data during the initial get request that the enduser may edit and post back. The data supplied by `data` or `obj` would therefore never be expected to be validated by the form as this would be known valid data from the application or database. You will have to pass a multidict that supports the getlist method rather than a simple dict to `formdata` however. You could use either a werkzeug MultiDict or a django MultiValueDict for the purpose.

```
from werkzeug import MultiDict
from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators

class UserForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[validators.Optional(), validators.Email()]

form = UserForm(formdata=MultiDict({'email': 'lem'}))
form.validate()
```